# How to add `this` qualifier to Java fields in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, this, qualifiers

Is there any functionality in Eclipse to refactor my code such that unqualified field accesses gain the `this` qualifier? For example, I had been writing some of my code in static methods but would now like to change them to non-static methods. I prefer styling my code with `this` so that it's more clear and readable.

I would like an easy way for the `foo` and `bar` here:

```
public class Example
{
    private static String foo = "Hovercraft";
    private static int bar = 9001;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println(foo + " has " + bar + " eels.");
    }
}
```

to turn into `this.foo` and `this.bar` after I change the code to use non-static methods:

```
public class Example
{
    private String foo;
    private int bar;

    public class Example(String theFoo, int theBar)
    {
        this.foo = theFoo;
        this.bar = theBar;
    }

    public void run()
    {
        System.out.println(this.foo + " has " + this.bar + " eels.");
    }
}
```

Of course it would be easy to add `this.` manually if the code is short like this, but suppose I have a rather large piece of code with at least a few dozen unqualified field accesses. How would I go about doing this automatically in Eclipse? I can't use "Refactor > Rename" because that won't let me use `this.foo` for the name, and using "Find/Replace" is a pain since it will also change the declarations and possibly other local variables that were named the same.

I found one way to do this after poking around more just before posting this question so I will add it as an answer, but I'm wondering if I'm missing other obvious ways to do this.

Answer (score 7):

Eclipse offers automatic code cleanup under "Source > Clean Up". To add the `this` qualifier automatically when cleaning up, "Configure" the cleanup profile
[image]

Then under "Member Accesses" check the "Non static accesses" boxes and select "Always".
[image]

"OK > Finish" should then add `this.` to any unqualified accesses.